# Drupal Web Form put on the content

Tags: webforms

How can I move the Web form from the bottom of the content area to the top of content area?

Where is the setting for this? Is it possible to move where the webform is displayed? The web form is in the bottom, and I need it to be in the top.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with your theme.

In your [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.tpl.php/7) (or any of it's derived tpl.php files, like node--CONTENTTYPE.tpl.php) you'll likely see a point where something like this is going on:

```
print render($content);
```

before that content is rendered, add

```
print render($content['webform']);
hide($content['webform']);
```

so the full code code snippet should look something like:

```
<?php
print render($content['webform']);
hide($content['webform']);
print render($content);
?>
```

Basically what your doing is telling drupal to:

1. render out the webform.
2. hid the the webform from any other render attempts.
3. render out the rest of the page content.

Another option would be to render out the webform as a block, which would mean you could load it in any other part of the site. The option for that would be located in the webform's individual edit screen, under form settings, advanced settings (down at the bottom), and "Available as block."

Answer (score 1):

If you enabled this Webform to have a block, then go to Structure ->blocks, look for a webform block, move it to the top content region or in the highlighted region.